# Http POST request with json content-type in dart:io

Tags: dart, dart-io

How to perform HTTP POST using the console dart application (using `dart:io` or may be `package:http` library. I do something like that:

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:io';

  http.post(
    url,
    headers: {HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE: "application/json"},
    body: {"foo": "bar"})
      .then((response) {
        print("Response status: ${response.statusCode}");
        print("Response body: ${response.body}");
      }).catchError((err) {
        print(err);
      });
```

but get the following error:

```dart
Bad state: Cannot set the body fields of a Request with content-type "application/json".
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From `http.dart`:

> ```
> /// [body] sets the body of the request. It can be a [String], a [List<int>] or
> /// a [Map<String, String>]. If it's a String, it's encoded using [encoding] and
> /// used as the body of the request. The content-type of the request will
> /// default to "text/plain".
> ```

So generate the JSON body yourself (with [`JSON.encode` from dart:convert](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/yYOwLNA6p1c)).

Comment: It works but with the wrong content type... If the remote server uses content negociation, it will not recognize the request body as JSON (and will not parse it as an object).

Comment: @CédricBelin — The content type is not wrong. The code already in the question was setting it to the right value for a JSON body.

Comment: @Quentin Absolutely, you're right : not enough concentrated when I read the documentation of the package "http" => `The content-type of the request will be set [...] this cannot be overridden`

This sentence was associated with a `Map` body, not a `String` one.

Comment: If I do such a thing I am not able to retreive the request with  $_POST in PHP side of the project. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: @Martin. — PHP only supports url encoded and multipart form encoded requests for automatic decoding to $_POST (i.e. not JSON encoded requests).

Answer (score 70):

This is a complete example. You have to use `json.encode(...)` to convert the body of your request to JSON.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';


var url = "https://someurl/here";
var body = json.encode({"foo": "bar"});

Map<String,String> headers = {
  'Content-type' : 'application/json', 
  'Accept': 'application/json',
};

final response =
    http.post(url, body: body, headers: headers);
final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
print(responseJson);
```

Generally it is advisable to use a `Future` for your requests so you can try something like

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

Future<http.Response> requestMethod() async {
    var url = "https://someurl/here";
    var body = json.encode({"foo": "bar"});

    Map<String,String> headers = {
      'Content-type' : 'application/json', 
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    };

    final response =
        await http.post(url, body: body, headers: headers);
    final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
    print(responseJson);
    return response;
}
```

The only difference in syntax being the `async` and `await` keywords.