# Flutter POST request body not sent

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to make a post request in Flutter with the following code:

```
// Body: {"email": "example@email.com", "pass": "passw0rd"}

Future<dynamic> post(String url, var body) async {
  var response = await http.post(url, body: body);
  final String res = response.body;
  return res;
}

// That's not the full code. I removed some lines because they are useless for this thread.
// Most of them are only some debug outputs or conditional statements
```

The problem is that my post request doesn't include the body with my request. I checked that with some outputs on my server.

Comment: Try sending the request to `httpbin.org/post` which will echo the request. Perhaps you are missing a request header. Can you perform a valid post with curl or Postman?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just have to encode the body before sending:

```
import 'dart:convert';
...

var bodyEncoded = json.encode(body);
var response = await http.post(url, body: bodyEncoded , headers: {
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
},);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I also had to add "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" to the headers to make it work.

Comment: For me it was `headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}` :)
See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27574740/http-post-request-with-json-content-type-in-dartio