# type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'String'?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

**How to solve this error i could not solved yet anyone help how to fix error..............................................................................................................................................................................................................**

```
home.dart
  final List _bannerImage = [];

  getBanner() {
    _service.home.get().then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
        setState(() {
          _bannerImage.add(['image']);
        });
      });
    });
  }

Container(
              height: 140,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              color: Colors.grey,
              child: PageView.builder(
                itemCount: _bannerImage.length,
                onPageChanged: (val) {
                  setState(() {
                    scrollPosition = val.toDouble();
                  });
                },
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return CachedNetworkImage(
                    imageUrl: _bannerImage[index],
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    placeholder: (context, url) => GFShimmer(
                      showShimmerEffect: true,
                      mainColor: Colors.grey.shade500,
                      secondaryColor: Colors.grey.shade400,
                      child: Container(
                        height: 140,
                        child: const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );

                  //   Image.network(
                  //   _bannerImage[index],
                  //   fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  // );
                },
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58743572/type-listmapstring-string-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-string-in-type-cast This may help

Comment: Hey Aakib below answer solved you problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is here you add list instead of image url

```
_bannerImage.add(['image']);
```

You need to add image url like this

```
_bannerImage.add(doc['image']);
```